# jQuery Click link to show var div images with div title in two locations simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When a text menu is clicked, a photo fadeIn and the title also FadeIn placed in a separate location. I am having trouble integrating the titles. If there is a better method of doing this, I would appreciate your help.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Tacbs/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div#photos, div#photo-titles").hide();
var divs = $("#Photo1, Photo1-Title, #Photo2,  Photo2-Title, #Photo3, Photo3-Title,");
$("li a").click(function () {
$(divs).hide();
$("#" + $(this).attr("class")).fadeIn();
});
});​

#photo-titles {
margin-top: 0;
}
#photos {
margin-top: 100px;
}
#photo-titles {
margin-top: 200px;
}​

<div id="photo-links">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="Photo1 Photo1-Title">Photo 1 Button</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="Photo2 Photo2-Title">Photo 2 Button</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="Photo3 Photo3-Title">Photo 2 Button</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="photos">
<div id="Photo1"><img src="Photo1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="Photo2"><img src="Photo1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="Photo3"><img src="Photo1.jpg"/></div>
</div>

<div id="photo-titles"> // text
<div id="Photo1-Title">Photo Title 1</div>
<div id="Photo2-Title">Photo Title 2</div>
<div id="Photo3-Title">Photo Title 3</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things, I think you are using too many ids. This is much better controlled with classes. If you are trying to do multiple things at once, that is why a class exists (sort of). With ids, you'd have to isolate each one. So I changed some ids to classes and got it working well.

HTML

```
<div id="photo-links">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="Photo1">Photo 1 Button</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="Photo2">Photo 2 Button</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="Photo3">Photo 3 Button</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="photos">
<div class="Photo1 hide"><img src="Photo1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="Photo2 hide"><img src="Photo1.jpg"/></div>
<div class="Photo3 hide"><img src="Photo1.jpg"/></div>
</div>

<div id="photo-titles">
<div class="Photo1 hide">Photo Title 1</div>
<div class="Photo2 hide">Photo Title 2</div>
<div class="Photo3 hide">Photo Title 3</div>
</div>​
```

JS
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
$("#photos, #photo-titles, .hide").hide();


$("li a").click(function () {
    $("#photos, #photo-titles, .hide").hide(); // Hide everything every time
    var c = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0]; // Get first class of link
    $("." + c).parent().show(); // Show the parent div
    $("." + c).fadeIn(); // Show the object you want to show
    });
});​
```

There is probably a slightly more efficient way to do this, but it works well.

**UPDATE**
I realized I created that hide class and didn't explain it. First of all, it depends on whether or not you want to hide the parent divs `#photos` and `#photo-titles`. That will depend on what you are using them for. If you don't need to hide those divs themselves, and just everything inside them, you can delete the `#photos, #photo-titles` from the `hide()` call as well as the line `$("." + c).parent().show();` since the parents will always be shown. And then you can just hide the `.hide` classes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I tried your method but I could not get it to work - http://jsfiddle.net/dD7AH/5/ any ideas?

Comment: Just missing the `$(document).ready(function()` at the beginning. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/JDewzy/dD7AH/6/.

Comment: You can do a lot with classes and those jQuery selectors. It's really useful for pairing things that work together or simultaneously in jQuery. There are also tons of extra selectors. You could use `siblings()` to hide the other divs as well. There really are a ton of solutions to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You had a lot of logic missing, missing `#` ID selectors, and also you were grabbing the div's you wanted to show by `.attr('class')` but not splitting them up by spaces and selecting them.

http://jsfiddle.net/6krwX/

```
$("div#photos, div#photo-titles").hide();

// you were missing # ID selector for some selectors here
var divs = $("#Photo1, #Photo1-Title, #Photo2,  #Photo2-Title, #Photo3, #Photo3-Title");

$("li a").click(function () {

    $(divs).hide();
    $('#photos, div#photo-titles').show(); // show the areas

    var locations = $(this).attr('class').split(' '); // split the classes up

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        $("#" + locations[i]).show(); // show photo & title
    }
});
```

There could be either improvements made, but the jist is there and it's working!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I could not have figure this out myself.

Comment: @Phillip Anytime! Glad to help. In the future always check your console for errors, and also try to `console.log()` certain selector variables to see if they are correct / working!